# Javascript задать css-класс при создании

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как задать css-класс компоненту при его создании динамически. Кусок кода:

```
tmode = document.createElement('td'); 
tmode.setAttribute('id', "td_0" + t_index);
selector = document.createElement('select');   
selector.setAttribute('id', "tmode" + t_index);
tmode.appendChild(selector);  
for (i=0; i<3; i++) { // Добавляем итемы в selector
    items = document.createElement('option');
    items.innerHTML = tmode_values[i];
    selector.appendChild(items);
}
tmode.appendChild(selector);
```

Вот что хочу получить:

```
<select class="basic" id='tmode1'>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: selector.setAttribute("class", "basic");

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы установить class, нудно обратиться к свойству `className` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/className)) элемента.

```
selector.className = "basic";
```

Так же есть `classList` с более мощным функционалом - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: Спасибо большое, проблема решена!!!

Comment: @fin проверил, все работает https://jsfiddle.net/L1bm01sg/

Answer (score 1):

Добавление класса для `element` : `element.classList.add('');`

В вашем случае так:
`selector.classList.add('basic')`